# How to dispatch a Laravel job using tinker to a specific queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, tinker

Trying to master my Laravel queues. I've got a production Laravel site using Redis queues managed by Horizon. There's one queue called 'default' for basic jobs, and another called 'long-running-queue' with a longer timeout.

Some of my longer jobs run via the scheduler overnight on the 'long-running-queue', which works reliably.

But sometimes I need to re-run these longer jobs during the day. I've figured out how to do this for quick jobs using \Bus::dispatch() from tinker (php artisan tinker), but cannot seem to dispatch  them to the long-running-queue; they always stay on the default.

It seems that something like this should work from the Tinker console:

```
\Bus::dispatch(new \App\Jobs\MyJob('MyArg'))->onQueue('long-running-queue')
```

...but it gives this:

```
PHP Error:  Call to a member function onQueue() on string in /home/mywebappeval()'d code on line 1
```

Can't seem to fine a posted solution to this problem anywhere. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `onQueue()` of the instance of the job, you are calling it on the result of the dispatch method.

```
$job = (new \App\Jobs\MyJob('MyArg'))->onQueue('long-running-queue');

Bus::dispatch($job);
```